# Restrict resource types only to XHR's with playwright

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

I want to return only the `xhr` from `scrapy_playwright` using the `playwright_page_event_handlers`. After checking the jsonlines file, I find that it has not succesfully restricted to only the xhrs.

I know I can filter before writing the file, however I want to save the amount of time it takes to grab these resources rather than filtering everything after.

How can I restrict the resource types only to `xhr`?

Here's what I have tried:

```
from playwright.async_api import Response as PlaywrightResponse, BrowserContext
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import jsonlines

class EventSpider(Spider):
    name = "event"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll",
            cookies={"foo": "bar", "asdf": "qwerty"},
            meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_page_coroutines = [
                    PageCoroutine("wait_for_selector", "div.quote"),
                    PageCoroutine("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"),
                    PageCoroutine("wait_for_selector", "div.quote:nth-child(11)"),  # 10 per page
                ],
                playwright_page_event_handlers={
                    "response": "handle_response",
                    "context": self.configure_context
                },
            ),
        )
    async def configure_context(name: str, context: BrowserContext) -> None:
        def handle_route(route):
            if ("quotes" in route.request.post_data):
                route.fulfill()
            else:
                route.continue_()
        await context.route("/api/**", handle_route)

    async def handle_response(self, response: PlaywrightResponse) -> None:
        jl_file = "test.jl"
        data = {response.request.resource_type:[response.request.url]}
        with jsonlines.open(jl_file, mode='a') as writer:
            writer.write(data)

    def parse(self, response):
        return {"url": response.url}
```

Produces the following output:

```
{"document": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll"]}
{"stylesheet": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/static/bootstrap.min.css"]}
{"stylesheet": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/static/main.css"]}
{"script": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/static/jquery.js"]}
{"stylesheet": ["https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700"]}
{"font": ["https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v26/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2"]}
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=1"]}
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=2"]}
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=3"]}
```

Expected output:

```
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=1"]}
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=2"]}
{"xhr": ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=3"]}
```